# gridster.js - Отключить Drag&drop внутри виджета

Tags: jquery, виджет

Внутри виджета — элементы, которые тоже надо перетаскивать.

Получается, что и элемент двигается и сам виджет.

Надо бы оставить возможность перетаскивания за заголовок, а дальше отключить.

Сделал я ещё один `div` с классом `disable_widget_move`, предполагая, чтобы при наведении на него отключить D&D виджета. но я не нашёл такой функции у `gridster.js`, только полное отключение у всех виджетов, и оно тоже у меня не работает (ну, наверно заработает если брать не `li` а `ul`, но суть не в этом).

```
$( ".disable_widget_move" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).parents('li').gridster().data('gridster').disable();
    console.log($(this).parents('li.widget_gridster'));
});
```

Может быть, есть варианты по изящней?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".disable_widget_move" ).hover(
    function() { $(this).parents('ul').gridster().data('gridster').disable();},
    function() { $(this).parents('ul').gridster().data('gridster').enable();}    
);
```

Ну так работает. вопрос остаётся в том что может в этом плагине это уже реализовано, и я просто не в курсе?

---

да вроде вполне работает, просто надо идти спать...